# Variable referencing vs. repetitive get calls to avoid null pointers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a situation in my code where I make about 5 chained get calls, and any of those get calls could return a null value. I wish it didn't have to be that way, but that's just how the service I'm consuming returns the object I request, so I have to deal with it.

Originally, my code looked something like this:

```
String firstDomain = book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults().getDomain().get(0);
```

Unfortunately, that line is prone to null pointers and arraylist out of bounds exceptions. I know I'm going to have to check for null pointers, but I'm trying to decide

A. The most efficient code to do so

and

B. The best looking code to do so

One option is to assign a ton of references and then check for nulls. Something like this:

```
BookImages bImages = book.getBookImages();
Domains domains = null;
Defaults defaults = null;
List<String> domain = null;
String firstDomain = null;
if (bImages != null) {
    domains = bImages.getDomains();
    if (domains != null) {
        defaults = domains.getDefaults();
        if (defaults != null) {
            domain = defaults.getDomain();
            if (domain != null && domain.size() > 0) {
                firstDomain = domain.get(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (firstDomain == null) {
    throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
}
```

I think that's pretty efficient, but it bothers me how many lines it is. It more than doubles the length of the method it is a part of.

This is the other alternative I can think of:

```
if (book.getBookImages() == null || book.getBookImages().getDomains() == null || book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults() == null || book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults().getDomain() == null || book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults().getDomain().size() < 1 || book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults().getDomain().get(0) == null) {
    throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
}
```

I like the fact that that's only three lines, even if one is pretty darn ridiculous, but I'm not sure if Java's runtime or compiler would optimize away those repetitive method calls.

I'm also open to other, better solutions. Does anyone know if one or the other of those options would perform better than the other, or is this such a micro-optimization that it's foolish to even bother thinking about it, and I should just use whichever looks nicer to me? I may have to do this many times for different things.

Comment: Ideally method's shouldn't return null but return a version of the object which represents null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Szymon pointed out you should not call same method twice.

To make your original solution slightly more readable by combining all your nested `null` checks into one:

```
        BookImages bImages = null;
        Domains domains = null;
        Defaults defaults = null;
        List<String> domain = null;
        String firstDomain = null;

        if ((bImages = book.getBookImages()) != null
                && (domains = bImages.getDomains()) != null
                && (defaults = domains.getDefaults()) != null
                && (domain = defaults.getDomain() != null
                && domain.size() > 0) {

                        firstDomain = domain.get(0);

        }
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is a nice idea. I believe in general making assignments in logical checks is frowned on, but this seems like a good use case for it.

Comment: "making assignments in logical checks is frowned on" - never heard of this. See similar code everywhere, including android sdk and tons of other legacy code. Where did you get this idea from ?

Comment: Maybe I'm conflating making assignments with modifying state. For example, I've heard that `if (mySet.add(anObject)){ ... }` isn't generally something you want to do. I believe the reasoning is that people expect logical checks to not modify state, so it can be a little confusing. But that may have just been close-minded advice from a code review from who-knows-when.

Comment: Well, perhaps you have your point. However, there is almost a standard practice to write this code `while((line = reader.nextLine()) !=null) {// reading input stream}`. Looks familiar i believe ? This is one example of the top of my head, but I encounter many others regularly.

Answer (score 2):

To follow your second approach, you can apply this:

```
    if ((bImages=book.getBookImages()) == null
            || (domains=bImages.getDomains()) == null
            || (defaults=domains.getDefaults()) == null
            || (domain=defaults.getDomain()) == null
            || domain.size() < 1
            || (firstDomain=domain.get(0)) == null) {
        throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
    } else {
        //here you can use the firstDomain variable, that is set with the correct value
    }
```

This is better because you avoid multiple (useless) identical calls, and you already set the correct value in the variable firstDomain (of course, only if there is nothing null and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about the length of the code too much if the longer code is correct and shorter incorrect. The goal of programming is not writing the shortest possible code (with the exception of some competitions, etc).

Your first (longer) way is correct, even if a bit longish.

The second way will make repeated calls to the same method. This is something you probably want to avoid - it may have undesirable effects and is worse for performance.

Comment: I agree that I generally prefer more correct code over shorter code. Sometimes code can be too short, even (less readable). However, in this case I believe this code being longer detracts from its readability, since the null checks' length just gets in the way of seeing the rest of the method's real logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a boolean method; they tend to make logic a lot simpler and much more legible; for example, I would do this:

```
public boolean isCompletelyAttributed(BookImages bImages) {
    if (bImages == null) return false;
    if (bImages.getDomains() == null) return false;
    if (bImages.getDomains().getDefaults() == null) return false;
    if (bImages.getDomains().getDefaults().getDomains() == null) return false;

    return bImages.getDomains().getDefaults.getDomains.size() > 0;
}
```

Then you call

```
if (!isCompletelyAttributed(book.getImages())) {
    throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
}
```

I also recommend that you use Nicola or kiruwka's solution in your boolean method. I was not aware that you could reassign variables while doing logic on them, but that appears to be an elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a short-ish way to do it. But hey, I don't know the specifics of what you're building and whether this works for you.

```
try {
    String firstDomain = book.getBookImages().getDomains().getDefaults().getDomain().get(0);
    // operate on firstDomain
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    throw new IncompleteBookException("The book was incompletely attributed.");
}
```

I've heard that people are concerned with the performance of something like this, because the VM will have to fill in a stack trace for the `NullPointerException`. In this case, you'll already be doing a comparable operation for the `IncompleteBookException` anyway.

Comment: This is short but worse. What if one of the methods is broken and throws a null pointer exception? If you know the methods are good, then this might be ok.

Comment: You should not use exceptions to control the flow of your code. Exceptions should be reserved for unexpected situations.

Comment: agreed, kinda. But you'd have to know whether null values are exceptional or not. For example, if a precondition of this method is that the book is "complete," and this null-checking code is only to help add more helpful debugging information, then this kind of approach isn't "using exceptions to control the flow of your code."

Comment: @guest You could have NullPointerException happening inside any of the methods and you couldn't then tell this genuine exception from your flow control.

Comment: yeah, this behaves considerably differently if you need unrelated `NullPointerException`s to propagate. Again, use with discretion.

Comment: They are practically all just getters, so there is little danger of null pointers being thrown from them, but I couldn't stop someone else from making one of them into a logical getter, and then this could mask null pointers created by something like that. A little far-fetched, but I'd prefer to not do it this way.